# Python/Pygame: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, pygame

My Pygame code returns an error stating:

```
apple.rect=pygame.rect(apple_x,apple_y,32,37)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

My complete code is as follow:

```
import sys, pygame, random
from menu_lib import *
from credit import credit

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, *groups):
        super(Player, self).__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('catcher_left.png')
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((320,240), self.image.get_size())
        self.rect.bottom = 452
        self.rect.left = 320

    def update(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= 10
            self.image = pygame.image.load('catcher_left.png')
            pygame.display.flip()
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += 10
            self.image = pygame.image.load('catcher_right.png')
            pygame.display.flip()
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        elif self.rect.right > 640:
            self.rect.right = 640
        if self.rect.colliderect(apple.rect):
            print "Collided!"

class Game(object):
    def main(self, screen):
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')
        background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (640, 480))
        apple = pygame.image.load('apple.png')
        apple_x=0
        apple_y=0
        apple_count=0
        sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(sprites)

        while 1:
            clock.tick(30)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    screen.fill((0,0,0))
                    pygame.display.flip()
                    Mainmenu()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    screen.fill((0,0,0))
                    pygame.display.flip()
                    Mainmenu()

            if apple_y==0:
                apple_y+=10
                apple_x=random.randint(10, 630)
                apple_count+=1
            elif apple_y!=0 and apple_y<480:
                apple_y+=10
            elif apple_y>=480:
                apple_y=0
                apple_x=0
            apple.rect=pygame.rect(32,37,apple_x,apple_y)

            sprites.update()
            screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            sprites.draw(screen)
            score_txt='Score: '+str(apple_count)
            label = myfont.render(score_txt, 1, (255,0,0))
            screen.blit(label, (500, 10))
            screen.blit(apple, (apple_x,apple_y))
            pygame.display.flip()


def Mainmenu():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    menu = cMenu(50, 50, 20, 5, 'vertical', 300, screen,
           [('Start Game', 1, None),
            ('Credits',    2, None),
            ('Exit',       3, None)])

    menu.set_center(True, True)

    menu.set_alignment('center', 'center')

    state = 0
    prev_state = 1

    rect_list = []

    pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEMOTION)

    while 1:
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if prev_state != state:
         pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(EVENT_CHANGE_STATE, key = 0))
         prev_state = state

        e = pygame.event.wait()

        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN or e.type == EVENT_CHANGE_STATE:
         if state == 0:
            rect_list, state = menu.update(e, state)
         elif state == 1:
             screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
             Game().main(screen)
         elif state == 2:
             credits()
         else:
            print 'Exit!'
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
         pygame.quit()
         sys.exit()

        pygame.display.update(rect_list)

def credits():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    text = "Credits \n _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ \n\n\n Designer \n Creator \n\n Manikiran P"
    color = 0xa0a0a000
    credit(text,myfont,color)
    Mainmenu()
    while 1:
        clock.tick(30)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                screen.fill((0,0,0))
                pygame.display.flip()
                Mainmenu()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                screen.fill((0,0,0))
                pygame.display.flip()
                Mainmenu()

        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Evenure - (c) 2014")
    myfont = pygame.font.Font("captureit.ttf", 20)
    apple_x=0
    apple_y=0
    apple = pygame.image.load('apple.png')
    Mainmenu()
```

I am trying to create a rectangle of apple, for purpose of collision but ended up get the above error. If i remove the rectangle and the collision statements, It works super fine. Hoping to get the correction as soon as possible. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `pygame.Rect()` (uppercase R); `pygame.rect` is the module defining the `Rect` type, but it is also available in the top-level module.

In one location you are using it correctly:

```
self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((320,240), self.image.get_size())
```

Update the problematic line to:

```
apple.rect = pygame.Rect(32, 37, apple_x, apple_y)
```

or

```
apple.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(32, 37, apple_x, apple_y)
```

However, `apple` is a a [`Surface` object](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html), which does not *have* a `rect` attribute, so this will throw an exception.

Perhaps you wanted to clip the image? Use [`Surface.set_clip()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_clip) for that.

If you expected a `Surface` object to act like a sprite, then you'll first need to create an actual sprite object. If you don't yet know how to create a sprite, you'll need to read up on sprites first:

- Tutorials on sprites:

  - http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/SpriteIntro.html
  - [http://thepythongamebook.com/en:pygame:step014](http://thepythongamebook.com/en%3apygame%3astep014)
  - http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites
- [Sprite class documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite).

Comment: After changing, the following error occurs:
apple.rect=pygame.Rect(32,37,apple_x,apple_y)
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect'

Comment: @Evenure: exactly. Or `pygame.rect.Rect` if you want to be consistent throughout your code.

Comment: After changing, the following error occurs: apple.rect=pygame.Rect(32,37,apple_x,apple_y) AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect'

Comment: @Evenure: so `apple` is a `pygame.Surface` instance. What did you expect it to be?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to say, i am very new to pygame!

Comment: @Evenure: I am not sure what you wanted to do with the image. `pygame.image.load()` returns a [`Surface` object](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html), which does *not* have a `rect` attribute. Perhaps you wanted to clip the image? Use [`Surface.set_clip()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_clip) for that.

Comment: Sorry, but i want the apple's rectangle to get collision with the player!

Comment: @Evenure: but it is not a sprite! It is a surface object.

Comment: So can you suggest me a code to change apple to sprite and then try to collide with the player

Comment: @Evenure: that is too broad; why not [follow a tutorial on sprites](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites) first?

Comment: Thank you very much, i will check it later, i have to go! TC